# JavaFX inserting an image

Tags: java, javafx

Ok, I am very, very new to Java and am self taught, so no making fun of my bad coding ;)
I am messing around with Java fx and am trying to insert an image into a borderpane layout.

this is the method that is in the controller I am using to make an image appear but I cant get the filepath to work.  It currently has "/images/brownBear.jpg" as the filepath, but I've tried the relative path-

> com/jaimependlebury/mammal/images/brownBear.jpg

and the full path and everything in between and i either get a

> FileNotFoundException

or

> NullPointerErrorException

I'm not even sure I set it up correctly, I've found different things on different websites and have tried to piece information together, so any help would be appreciated.

FXML file

```
<ImageView fx:id="picture">
</ImageView>
```

Controller file-

I have the ImageView picture variable declared at the top of the class, I just didn't include it in the code block.

```
 @FXML
public void handleMammalListView()throws FileNotFoundException {
    Species species= mammalList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    picture=new ImageView();
    Image img =new Image(new FileInputStream("/images/brownBear.jpg"));
    picture.setImage(img);
            speciesName.setText(species.getSpeciesName());
    details.setText(
                    "Scientific name: "  + species.getScientificName() +"\n"+
                    "Staus: " +    species.getStatus() + "\n" +
                    "Distribution: " + species.getHabitat() +"\n" +
                    "Food: " + species.getFood() + "\n" +
                    "Birth: " + species.getBirth() + "\n" +
                    "Distinguishing Characteristics: " + species.getBodyType() + "\n"+
                    "Nursing: " + species.getNurse() + "\n" +
                    "Type of hair: " + species.getTypeOfHair());
```

Comment: You don't need this - picture=new ImageView(); since you are injecting this with FXML.  This will reset the reference and it won't display on the UI.

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: I will make this the answer - can you please accept it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code:

```
picture=new ImageView();
```

Is resetting the reference you set in your FXML - you can just remove it.